How to prevent GNOME desktop from suspending when an SSH session is active?
I'm running Ubuntu 22 desktop. From time to time, I would also like to run the machine with active SSH sessions from different users like a server.
Is there a way to configure GNOME (or Ubuntu in general) to prevent the desktop idle suspension when there is an active SSH session? I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require disabling suspension entirely, but only when SSH is in use. I have configured wake-on-lan so that I remotely resume the machine from suspension.
It seems like the major tooling available is gnome-session-inhibit. So I tried adding this code to sshd_config:
ForceCommand gnome-session-inhibit --inhibit suspend:idle --reason "SSH Session"  bash

But this doesn't quite work. If a user tries to connect but they don't already have logged onto their gnome session, this command throws an error.
I also looked into adjusting the idle suspension via gsetting
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'

But that doesn't seem to work either for the same reason.
Thanks in advance!
